# Where is Powershell NetSecurity module?

Tags: powershell

I can't seem to find the `NetSecurity` module on my system. I am using an `Amazon Windows 2008 Server R2 SP1` instance.

`Get-Module -ListAvailable` on my environment returns this:

```
ActiveDirectory (I installed this)    
ADRMS    
AppLocker    
BestPractices    
BitsTransfer    
CimCmdlets    
ISE    
Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics/Host/Management/Security/Utility    
Microsoft.WSMan.Management    
PSDiagnostics    
PSScheduledJob    
PSWorkflow    
PSworkflowUtility    
ServerManaer    
TroubleshootingPack
```

I have tried to install `WMF 3.0`, but it was reported to be already installed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The are [new modules in powershell 3.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801904.aspx) that are **only included** as part of the roles/features that ship with **Windows Server 2012**, and in some cases they are also **available on Windows 8**. Unfortunately, they cannot be installed on previous versions of Windows, and `NetSecurity` is one of this module

Comment: Tks. Looks like COM object is the only way for me to manipulate firewall rules now.

Comment: I'm working on module for Vista/2008+ that implements the important firewall related cmdlets from the NetSecurity module. It will be finished soon and available on github. I'll post on my [blog](http://andyarismendi.blogspot.com) when its ready for distribution.