# Missing Powershell 3.0 cmdlets in Windows 7 (Disable-NetAdapter)

Tags: powershell

On Windows 8 there are some PS cmdlets I can run like (Disable-NetAdapter, Get-Mailbox), but my scripts are failing on my Windows 7 machines.

I've confirmed the Windows 7 boxes have PS 3.0 installed.  I've also confirmed that Windows 7 just doesn't have those cmdlets.

Anyone know what gives?  Is there some sort of cmdlet import that I was supposed to perform?

Thanks all,
Joe

Comment: Read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262426/where-is-powershell-netsecurity-module/15263152#15263152

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple modules, including the net adapter and scheduled tasks modules, are only available in Windows 8/2012. As far as I know it's not possible to copy them to win7.

Comment: After additional research, I found that Microsoft extended WMI in Windows 8/2012 which accommodates additional modules.

Comment: You can create similar cmdlets for win7 in some cases, but Microsoft won't do it because it would be confusing. So you may be able to create some of them yourself if you need just a few